# I am well but is doing something - is 'is' correctly used here?

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence written by a native. But I am not familiar with this usage, please enlighten me.

"But I am well and is using this time to focus on preparation."

The verb "is" feels a bit weird in this sentence. I thought "am" would be more appropriate in the sentence where the subject is "I".

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you found such a strange thing?

Comment: It is certainly ungrammatical. It sounds Cockney. You might find some characters in Dickens using the form.

Comment: @Mick: I don't recall anyone in Dickens using "am" and "is" belonging to the same subject at the same time in the same sentence.

Comment: @Robusto Dickens was a bit of a wild guess. It sounds very familiar, and yet I can't place it.

Comment: @tchrist Thank God I am not the only one who thinks it's strange. I actually saw this on IG. She's Scottish btw, do they have a different grammar system?

Comment: It might just be a typing error. I make all sorts of howlers, especially when I change my mind about what I want to say.

Comment: @Mick Yep, could have been. Thanks so much for your insight. Xxx

Comment: Some social media sites have prompts that encourage talking about yourself in the third person. If you saw this on Instagram, they probably started out responding to the prompt, then added another thought but forgot to fix it up to be all in either first or third person.

Comment: @The Photon oh, that I didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: @Mick yes, it looks like an incomplete correction typo to me.